# Rest API invalid nonce with Backbone Client

Tags: javascript, rest-api, nonce, backbone

I'm using the built-in Backbone Client whenever I try to make a request it gives me this error: `{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}`

I read the [Rest API Handbook - Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), and from what I've learned I don't need to do any manual setting.

Plugins in use:

- Askimet Anti-spam
- WP Fastest Cache
- iThemes
- WP Bannerize
- Yoast

Side note: I'm using the client for for lazyloading and search.

Comment: What kind of API request are you trying?

Comment: Only `GET` requests of Posts collections. As I've said, just for lazyloading and search results.

Comment: A logout/login fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I delete `wpApiSettings.nonce` at the top of my app.js, perhaps not an ideal solution but it works.